# Access view data in custom Blade::if directive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Suppose I have a custom blade if directive, where I want to check if a variable exists in the view

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::if("exists", function() {
            return isset($model);
        });
    }
}
```

Currently the expression `isset($model)` will check for the variable `$model` in the context of the `AppServiceProvider`

Even though I could just pass the model and then do the ckeck, I am specifically looking for a solution without having to pass anything

How can I get the directive to be evaluated in the context in the view, Or how can get the data that was passed to the view?

**View** example:

```
<button type="submit">
@exists
    Save
@else
    Create
@endexists
</button>
```

**Controller**

```
return view("<path/to/view>", ["model" => $model];
```

Comment: Why do you want to check that? what are you trying to achieve? there's probably a better way of doing so. Also, in what condition do you have this variable in your view? maybe use that condition in your service provider as well.

Comment: @HTMHell The concrete use case shouldn't matter for this type of question. But anyways, I want to avoid creating the same form twice, one fore "storing" and one for editing. So my plan is to optionally pass a model to the view, if that model is set, I generate the form for editing the entity, if it is not, I generate for creating. I only want this "if" to conditionally add things like the form action

Comment: Then why do you need the service provider for that? What's wrong with something like that in the blade file: `{{ $model ? ' action="/"' : '' }}` (when creating, pass `"model" => null`)

Comment: @HTMHell I just find it awkward to use ternaries everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is just perfect, but you should pass the `$model` argument to `@exists` directive like below:

```
@exists($model)
<h1>It is there! :)</h1>
@else
<h1>It is not there! :(</h1>
@endexists
```

and you should pass `$model` as an argument to your new directive

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::if("exists", function($model) {
            return isset($model);
        });
    }
}
```

for more information about this subject, please check [Custom If Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-blade)
 in laravel  documentation

Comment: Yeah, I know I could just pass it. But I am looking for a solution without having to pass an argument, since that seems rather annoying. Thanks for your answer nonetheless, it seems like the only option

Comment: there is no way to achieve your idea like that